# cucumber example seems adding more items

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

I wanted to add 3 items, completed 1 of them, then go to filter the 'completed' items.

In the end of execution, I saw more items added.
is this constructed wrong?

```
Feature: filter todo item

  As a working adult with busy schedules
  I want to use todo app to filter todo item
  so that I can check todo item by status

  Scenario Outline: Filter todo item
    Given my todo list is empty
    When I add "First todo item #1"
    And I add "next todo item #2"
    And I add "next todo item #3"
    Then my todo list should has followings:
      | <Item Displayed> |
    When I complete "First todo item #1"
    Then the todo item called "First todo item #1" should be marked as completed
    And I filter the list to show Completed tasks
    Then my todo list should has followings:
      | <Item Displayed> |


    Examples:
      | Filter    | Item Displayed |
      | Completed | First todo item #1   |
      | Active    | next todo item #2 |
      | Active    | next todo item #3 |
```

error:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[tru]e> but was:<[fals]e>
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at todos.stepdefinitions.StepDefinitions.theTodoItemCalledShouldBeMarkedAsCompleted(StepDefinitions.java:88)
    at ✽.the todo item called "First todo item #1" should be marked as completed
```

this is the steps definitions:

```html
    public class StepDefinitions {
    
        @Steps
        AddNewTodoActions addTodo;
    
        @Steps
        TodoListActions todoItems;

        @Given("(?:.*) todo list is empty")
        public void fresh_todo() {
            navigate.toTheTodoMVCApplication();
        }
    
        @When("I add {string}")
        public void i_add(String todoItem) {
            addTodo.itemCalled(todoItem);
        }
    
        @Then("(?:.*) todo list should has followings:")
        public void todo_list_should_has_followings(List<String> expectedItems) {
            assertThat(todoItems.currentItems()).containsAll(expectedItems);
        }
    
        @And("the remaining item count is displayed as {string}")
        public void remaining_item_count_displayed(String remainingItemCountText) {
            assertThat(todoItems.numberOfItemsLeftMessage()).isEqualTo(remainingItemCountText);
        }
    
        @Given("I have a todo list containing")
        public void has_a_list_containing(List<String> expectedItems) {
            navigate.toTheTodoMVCApplication();
            addTodo.itemsCalled(expectedItems);
        }
    
        @Steps
        FilterItemsActions filterItems;
    
        @When("I filter the list to show {word} tasks")
        public void filtersBy(String filters) {
            filterItems.by(filters);
        }
    
        @Steps
        CompleteTodoActions completeTodo;
 
        @When("I complete {string}")
        public void complete(String completedTodo) {
            completeTodo.itemCalled(completedTodo);
        }
        @Then("the todo item called {string} should be marked as completed")
        public void theTodoItemCalledShouldBeMarkedAsCompleted(String todoItem) {       
            assertThat(completeTodo.isCompleted(todoItem)).isTrue();
        } 
    }
```

the editor suggested me to use scenario outline. so i just go ahead and change it.
let me know what should be the correct structure, just using scenario good enough?

Comment: You didn't share the glue code, thus it's hard to help. Did you go through debugging your code step by step?

Comment: Also I think you are misusing `Scenario Outline`s as your scenario will be executed once for each row in the `Examples` table which seems to not make sense in your case.

Comment: @GaëlJ i updated main post with steps definations.

Comment: i realize the item #1,2,3 being input 3 times. what should I modify to make the data input once according to the 'example'? or i need to add one more column in 'example' to indicate data input?

Comment: Either multiple columns or just don't use examples of you don't need them and put 3 rows in the first place in the step table.

Answer (score 0):

A scenario outline creates a separate scenario for each row in the examples column. I would suggest that as a new user to cucumber you avoid scenario outlines, there is no need for them and they just complicate things.

I'm a veteran Cuker (since before Cucumber was named). I don't ever use scenario outlines.

From your question it seems to me that what you are trying to do in this scenario is test filtering. A better scenario would make this clearer. How about

```
Feature: Filtering todo's

Scenario: View completed todo's
  Given I have some todo's
  And one todo is completed
  When I view my todo's
  And I filter on completed
  Then I should see only my completed todo
```

Note: How I am not describing how to do anything. This is the preferred way to Cuke.